Stuck trying to Streamtext and StreamUI simultaneously with Vercel's AI SDK
I have been trying to implement Vercels new AI SDK but keep running into issues.
I want to be able to stream text and UI as per the users request. Right now only the text gets streamed to the frontend, but the UI for some reason is not being streamed.
This is my action.tsx file:
'use server';

import { streamText } from 'ai';
import { openai } from '@ai-sdk/openai';
import { createStreamableUI, createStreamableValue } from 'ai/rsc';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { searchRecipes } from './recipe';
import { Recipe, RecipeCard } from '@/components/SingleRecipe';
import { RecipeCard2 } from '@/components/SingleRecipe2';

export interface Message {
  role: 'user' | 'assistant';
  content: string;
  display?: ReactNode;
}

interface RecipeSearchResults {
    recipes: Recipe[];
    total: number;
    skip: number;
    limit: number;
  }
  

export async function continueConversation(history: Message[]) {
  const stream = createStreamableValue();
  const streamUI = createStreamableUI();

  const { textStream, toolResults: toolResultsPromise } = await streamText({
    model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
    system: "You are a helpful assistant",
    messages: history,
    tools: {
      celsiusToFahrenheit: {
        description: 'Converts celsius to fahrenheit',
        parameters: z.object({
          value: z.string().describe('The value in celsius'),
        }),
        execute: async ({ value }) => {
          const celsius = parseFloat(value);
          const fahrenheit = celsius * (9 / 5) + 32;
          return `${celsius}°C is ${fahrenheit.toFixed(2)}°F`;
        },
      },
      writeApoem: {
        description: 'Write a poem based on a theme',
        parameters: z.object({
          theme: z.string().describe('The theme of the poem'),
        }),
        execute: async ({ theme }) => {
          let poem = '';
          const poemStream = await streamText({
            model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
            messages: [
              { role: 'user', content: `Write a poem about ${theme}` }
            ],
            maxTokens: 400,
          });

          for await (const chunk of poemStream.textStream) {
            stream.update(chunk);
          }

          return 'Poem written';
        }
      },
      explainTerms: {
        description: 'Explain terms used in the AEC industry',
        parameters: z.object({
          term: z.string().describe('The term to explain'),
        }),
        execute: async ({ term }) => {
            const explainStream = await streamText({
                model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
                system: "You are a professional Contractor",
                messages: [
                    { role: 'user', content: `Explain ${term}` }
                ],
                maxTokens: 400,
            })

            for await (const chunk of explainStream.textStream) {
                stream.update(chunk);
            }
        }
      },
      getRecipe: {
        description: 'Get a recipe based on ingredients',
        parameters: z.object({
          ingredients: z.string().describe('The ingredients to use'),
        }),
        execute: async ({ ingredients }) => {
          const result: RecipeSearchResults = await searchRecipes(ingredients);
          //console.log(result);
          streamUI.update(`...Searching for recipes based on ${ingredients}`);
          if (result.recipes.length === 0) {
            return 'No recipes found';
          }
          result.recipes.map(recipe => (
            streamUI.done(<RecipeCard2 recipe={recipe} />)
        ))
            return `Here's the recipe for ${ingredients}`;
        }
      }
    },
    onFinish: ({ usage }) => {
        const { promptTokens, completionTokens, totalTokens } = usage;

        console.log(`Prompt tokens: ${promptTokens}`);
        console.log(`Completion tokens: ${completionTokens}`);
        console.log(`Total tokens: ${totalTokens}`);
    }
  });

  (async () => {
    for await (const text of textStream) {
      stream.update(text);
    }

    if (toolResultsPromise) {
      const toolResults = await toolResultsPromise;
      for (const toolResult of toolResults) {
        if (toolResult.toolName !== 'writeApoem' && toolResult.toolName !== 'explainTerms') {
          stream.update(toolResult.result);
        }
      }
    }

    stream.done();
    console.log(streamUI.value);


  })();

  return {
    messages: history,
    newMessage: stream.value,
    display: streamUI.value,
  };
}

And my front end:
'use client';

import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { readStreamableValue } from 'ai/rsc';
import { Message, continueConversation } from '@/utils/actions';

export const maxDuration = 60;

export default function Chat() {
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState<React.ReactNode | null>(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    
    const userMessage: Message = { role: 'user', content: input };
    setConversation(prev => [...prev, userMessage]);
    setInput('');

    const { messages, newMessage } = await continueConversation([
      ...conversation.map(({ role, content }) => ({ role, content })),
      { role: 'user', content: input },
    ]);

    setConversation(messages);

    
    let assistantMessage: Message = { role: 'assistant', content: ''};
    setConversation(prev => [...prev, assistantMessage]);

    for await (const delta of readStreamableValue(newMessage)) {
      assistantMessage.content += delta;
      setConversation(prev => [
        ...prev.slice(0, -1),
        { ...assistantMessage },
      ]);
    }
    

    setIsLoading(false);
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.value = '';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full max-w-md py-24 mx-auto stretch">
      {conversation.map((m, index) => (
        <div key={index} className={`whitespace-pre-wrap mb-4 ${m.role === 'user' ? 'text-blue-600' : 'text-green-600'}`}>
          <strong>{m.role === 'user' ? 'User: ' : 'AI: '}</strong>
          {m.content}
          {m.display}
          
        </div>
      ))}

      {isLoading && (
        <div className="text-gray-500 italic">AI is thinking...</div>
      )}

      <form
        className="fixed bottom-0 w-full max-w-md p-2 mb-8 border border-gray-300 rounded shadow-xl space-y-2"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          className="w-full"
          onChange={event => {
            // Handle file upload logic here
          }}
          multiple
          ref={fileInputRef}
        />
        <input
          className="w-full p-2 border rounded"
          value={input}
          placeholder="Say something..."
          onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}
          disabled={isLoading}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded"
          disabled={isLoading}
        >
          {isLoading ? 'Processing...' : 'Send'}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

The tool calls celciustofarenheit, writeapoem and explainterms, are all text based and gets streamed to the front end. But the getRecipe tool call after being invoked does not show up.
I don't know if I'm processing the react component in the right way, or its not possible to stream text and UI.
I have been spinning wheels on this for a while trying to understand where I might have gone wrong..
